# LinkedQueues and simulated printer

Tags: python

I am aware that there is another post asking about simulated printers but I didn't find any actual answers to my own question there.

```
class LinkedQueue :

    class _Node :
        __slots__ = '_element', '_next'

        def __init__(self, element, next = None):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self) :
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self) :
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self) :
        return self._size == 0

    def first(self) :
        if self.is_empty() :
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        return self._head._element

    def dequeue(self) :
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        answer = self._head._element
        self._head = self._head._next
        self._size -= 1
        if self.is_empty() :
            self._tail = None
        return answer

    def enqueue(self, e) :
        newest = self._Node(e,None)
        if self.is_empty() :
            self._head = newest
        else :
            self._tail._next = newest
        self._tail = newest
        self._size += 1

class Printer:
   def __init__(self, name, job_queue):
     self._name = name
     self._job_queue
     self._current_job = None

class Empty(Exception) :
   pass

def main():
   p_jobs = LinkedQueue() 
   red = Printer("Red", p_jobs)                # Creates Printer Red
   green = Printer("Green", p_jobs)            # Creates Printer Green

   print("\nOptions:\n 1. Add Job \n 2. Print Pages \n 3. Status \
   \n 4. Quit")
   i = 0
   while True:
    n = str(input("\nChoice (Type the number): "))

    if n == '1':                            # Add Job
        i += 1
        p = int(input("\nHow many pages? "))
        j = p_jobs.job_list(i,p,next)
        p_jobs.enqueue(j)

    if n == '2':                            # Print Job
        print()
        p_jobs.dequeue()
        i -= 1


    if n == '3':                            # Status
        print()

    if n == '4':                            # Quit
        print("\nGoodbye!")
        break
```

This is the provided code for us. We are supposed to simulate two printers that print out pages from jobs using LinkedQueue and Node.

I have the main function barebones w/c consists of 4 options:
Add Job, Print Jobs, Status, and Quit

I have trouble understanding how to use (refer) to the  enqueue and dequeue methods. Can somebody break down each part of this program so I can at least understand where to start. I also would appreciate any hints that tell me where to go from here. Thank you.

EDIT: I added my main function w/c is basically just a UI

Comment: The code in your question makes little sense...and renders the rest of it meaningless. Also, what would a two printer simulation be or do?

Comment: This is what was given to us unfortunately. 
I just need to understand how to use the queue methods they gave us here at the very least. We are supposed to alter it(the whole code given so add or remove unnecessary stuff) to be able to simulate two printers 'Red' and 'Green' that take in job inputs from the main function and dequeue it when Print Jobs is called.

Comment: It's like when you are trying to print at a school printer. So sending it(enqueue) then print it (dequeue). BUT it assumes that there are two printers that can split all the incoming jobs. 
For example: Job 1 has 5 pages. Job 2 has 7 pages and Job 3 has 14 pages.
Job 1 goes to the first printer or 'Red' and Job 2 goes to goes to 'Green' while Job 3 waits till one printer finishes printing a job then it gets sent to that printer so Job 3 gets sent to 'Red' when Job 1 finishes dequeueing(or printing) its pages. It is simulated so I need to show progress using print statements.

Comment: I think you haven't inserted the code in your question correctly, which is causing it to be displayed improperly. To answer the part about using the two methods: If you have a class instance: e.g. `lnkque = LinkedQueue()`, then afterwards you can use them via `lnkque.enqueue(e)` and `lnkque.dequeue()`.

Comment: Regarding the rest of your question about doing the simulation: I think you need to also add the code you've written that isn't working that tries to do that part, then folks can maybe help you get it working.

Comment: I get that part. Sorry I wasn't more clear on this and yes I think the code isn't displaying properly. I'll see if I can fix that. But what I meant is in the context of the question that I don't know when exactly to use both methods. Like how do I go about putting those two things you posted. Should I call enqueue in the main function under Add Jobs and dequeue under Print Jobs? Also, how would I go about printing the progress of the program?

Comment: I think I fixed the code formatting in your question....and I still think what I said earlier about how to use the two methods is correct. To print the process of the program, I suppose you could show the length of the queue getting shorter along with the printers displaying something whenever one of them starts (and maybe finishes) printing something.

Comment: SORRY! I reverted the given code back to what was provided. I was playing around with it and ended up with the PrinterQueue name.

Comment: That's better. However, at this point I'm not sure what the problem is with respect to the `main()` function shown. Doesn't it work, and if not, in what way exactly?

Comment: It does work. It displays the UI properly. But that is where it ends. I have no idea if the enqueue and dequeue even works as intended. I don't have a way to display the third option which is status <- that is supposed to display all the jobs and how many pages they have all together after adding them. And if both enqueue and dequeue works, what is the next step to achieve what is intended by the program expected of us. Like displaying which Jobs are currently being printed or w/c page it is on currently and all that.

Comment: You're asking a very broad question—probably by too much to be on-topic here. One big thing is that It sounds like you may need to use threading to simulate the two `Printer`s running at the same time as the user interface. Beyond that somewhat complex effort, the `LinkedQueue` class needs one or more additional methods to allow its current contents to be examined/iterated over. These will allow you to implement displaying its status. Similarly, the `Printer` class needs methods added to allow its current state to be also examined/queried. With those it would become possible do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is by no means a complete answer, it shows how to print out what's currently in a `LinkedQueue` instance.

First, add the following method to the class. It will allow the contents to be iterated.

```
class LinkedQueue:

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return None  # No jobs in print queue.

        cur = self._head
        while cur:
            yield cur._element
            cur = cur._next
```

Here's something demonstrating how to use it:

```
def test():
    q = LinkedQueue()  # Create a queue.

    # Add some jobs to the LinkedQueue.
    for j in range(3):
        pages = randint(1, 10)
        q.enqueue(('job #{}'.format(j), pages))

    # Show what's currently in the LinkedQueue.
    for v in q:
        print(v)

    # Modify the LinkedQueue and then show what's left in it.
    j = q.dequeue()
    print('\nafter removing one job')
    for v in q:
        print(v)
```